# How to define a TS type/interface/etc. which is accessible via multiple files?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I would like to reuse a specific custom type i made in different files across my app, yet I have not quite managed to find a proper resource explaining how to do so.

```
src/sharedTypes.ts
src/file1.ts
src/file2.ts
```

**sharedTypes.ts:**

```
type MyPoint = {
   x: number;
   y: number;
}
```

I would like to be able to use this `MyPoint` type when working on `file1.ts` or `file2.ts`.

**for instance:**

```
const pointLog = (point: MyPoint): void => {
    console.log(`Point is located at: ${point.x}, ${point.y}.`);
}

pointLog({x:2, y:4});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `export` keyword

eg

```
 export type MyPoint = {
    x: number;
   y: number;
}
```

and then the `import` in the other file

```
 import { MyPoint } from './sharedTypes';
 const pointLog = (point: MyPoint): void => {
     console.log(`Point is located at: ${point.x}, ${point.y}.`);
 }

 pointLog({x:2, y:4});
```